# Open two files on startup - how to set vertical split as default?

Tags: init-file, window-splitting

When I invoke Emacs from the shell with the command `emacs fileA fileB`, I'd like to have the Emacs window split vertically (i.e. with one file on the left and one file on the right), not horizontally, to show the two buffers. How should I edit my .emacs configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care which file goes on the right and which file goes on the left, try the following init file:

```el
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)
(split-window-horizontally)
```

And yes: `split-window-horizontally` splits it vertically in your terminology :-) Emacs's terminology is different from yours.

Comment: It works. But now there's a minor annoyance - when I open just one file, with `emacs fileA` from the terminal, the screen is still split into two parts, with one part showing \*scratch\*. Is there a quick workaround?

Comment: I don't think so - in any case, I don't know one and a little investigation was fruitless. You might want to post it as a new question: that might attract some new eyes to it.